# Equivalent C++ struct for a SWIFT Hashable structure

Tags: c++

What would be the equivalent C++ struct codes for this swift struct?

```
struct MyStruct : Hashable {
    let rawValue: Int
    let x: UInt8
    let y: UInt16

    init(x: UInt8, y: UInt16) {
        self.rawValue = Int(x) << 24 | Int(y)
        self.x        = x
        self.y        = y
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(rawValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: `unordered_map<uint8_t, pair<int,uint16_t>>`

Comment: Please **read [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)**, then some good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/), then the C++ standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) and [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Notice that **C is not the same as C++.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unordered_map<uint8_t, uint16_t>`